# Why can't Bosch Detail Sander be converted as an oscillating tool?

Tags: tools

I recently purchased [Bosch 1294VSK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000302U5).  It comes with several adapters for hard-to-reach areas.  It moves in an oscillating motion.  I contacted their customer service dept to ask if it could be converted to be used as an oscillating tool for cutting in hard-to-reach corners but they said no.  Assuming they said so for liability reasons, I was wondering if there is still a possibility to macguiver/hack some oscillating functionality out of it and, if not, why that's the case.

Comment: Because that's the way the engineers designed it. It likely does not have enough power, and/or speed to be used for cutting.

Comment: so you called the manufacturer, and they told you it would be dangerous to do so, and now you are hoping someone here will give you the dangerous advise the manufacture specifically advised you against? thanks but no thanks!

Comment: they didn't say it would be dangerous

Answer (score 1):

The sander ans accessories are designed for each other.  The sanding pads are special sizes for that sander.

Not only are the accessories and sander made specifically for each other, but sander does not oscillate nearly fast enough for cutting.

If you pick up a dremmel multimax or milwuake multi-tool you will realize how fast they oscillate - you can hardly see that the bit is moving because it is so fast.

So I doubt that modding your sander to be a multi-tool would be dangerous - but I think that Bosch support was dead on: it wouldn't work.